# Проблема с передачей данных в Fragment (MVVM)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-sdk, viewmodel

Проект на MVVM.
На странице должны быть подгружены **3 списка**. (Выгружаются соответственно запросами через API с помощью `Retrofit`).  При старте страницы в методе `onViewCreated` вызывается метод из `viewmodel`, который загружает первых два списка. Третий список зависит от выбранного элемента из второго списка (на втором висит слушатель, который запускает запрос на третий список исходя из выборанного). В самой `viewmodel` меняется `MutableLiveData`, а `Fragment` все слушает. Все по стандарту. На каждый список свой `state`, в который приходит `List<>`, а потом присваивается в `Adapter`.
В нормальном режиме (обычный запуск `Fragment`) все работает. Как только **злые** тестировщики начинают играть с фоном приложения начинаются странности.
Если увести в фон приложение конкретно в момент, когда `viewmodel` должна изменить `state`, то она его не меняет. `Retrofit` все данные загружает (это проверенно). Метод `setValue` для изменения `state` срабатывает (в плане, что по логам до него доходит). Только **иногда** происходит вышеописанная ситуация. (**с postValue и setValue поигрался, результата не дало**)

**ViewModel**

```
retrofitService.getFirstList(iListsData = object : IListsData{
            override fun onSuccess(list: SpinnerList)                           
                 serviceState.set(ServiceState.LoadFirstList(list)
            }
            override fun onError(error: ErrorAPI) {
                 posState.set(MainStates.CriticalError(error.message))
            }
        })
```

**Fragment**

```
 is ServiceState.LoadFirstList -> {
                    binding.spinnerFirstList.apply {
                        adapter = SpinnerAdapter(requireContext(), state.list)
                        onItemSelectedListener = viewModel.listenerFirstList(state.list)
                    }
                }
```

Исходя из вышесказанного есть вопрос. Как избежать подобного поведения и добиться, чтобы `setValue` срабатывал, независимо в каком состоянии находится приложение.

**Update**
Не реагирует именно `Fragment`. `State` обновляется

Comment: а где происходит сет в лайвдату? вы сказали, что дергаете первых 2 метода во Фрагменте (что уже неправильно). поэтому предположу что и сетаете вы в лайвдату во ВьюМодели из Фрагмента. попробуйте перенести всью логику во ВьюМодель.

Comment: Сама лайвдата находится во viewmodel, "первые два метода" просто вызываются во view model из Fragment, как только будет выполнен ```onViewCreated```.

Comment: Метод, где находится "retrofitService.getFirstList" находится во view model. "MutableLiveData" находится и изменяется только во viewmodel.

Comment: `state` во `viewmodel` не обновляется или все-таки фрагмент на него не реагирует?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, фрагмент не реагирует. После ```set``` вывожу в логи и печатает нужное состояние

Comment: Так может он банально отписывается? Что-то с его жизненным циклом не так? Добавьте в логи проверку есть ли подписчики у `state`.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, нет возможности сейчас проверить. Если окажется, что он отписывается, то что в этом случае делать? И почему такое может происходить?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, проверил, ```state``` меняет. Подписчики есть